# splitting jobs with bsub command line

Tags: split, jobs, lsf

If the jobs are combined, LSF will only “look” for the needed resources for the first stage (compile) and launch the job since it doesn’t know about the simulation job at the end which needs various tokens.
I need to split the jobs with bsub command.
Can anyone please help me how splitting of jobs can be done with bsub command in lsf mode?

Comment: What are the tokens that are needed after first stage (compile)? Do you mean environment variables? Is it an option to save the tokens on file and then read them at the beginning of next job?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can utilize the [job dependency scheduling](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSETD4_9.1.3/lsf_admin/job_dep_sched.html) functionality and set the resources per job. [This page](https://scicomp.ethz.ch/wiki/Job_chaining) describes a couple of ways of chaining jobs with job dependency scheduling.
Below example gives the compile job and the next job different amount of memory:

```
bsub -R "rusage[mem=1]" -J job1 command1
bsub -R "rusage[mem=10]" -J job2 -w "done(job1)" command2
```